# 2004 Hyundai Elantra disable keyless entry

Tags: hyundai, elantra

I would like to fully disable keyless entry (and the alarm too) and use only keys. Is it sufficient to unplug all the cables from ETAC MODULE (ELANTRA ETAC MODULE 95400-2D510) behind the dashboard? And would it affect any other functionality?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you do that, your vehicle will not start. I don't know how to disable it, but that would be the way to disable the entire car. (It would be too easy for a thief to do this and steal the car if it weren't this way.)